# Django - iterate through 2 objects synchronously in the template form

Tags: django, templates

How do I iterate through 2 objects synchronously in the template form?

I have 2 objects in my views; one object is products, the other prices. Both are lists.
I want to cycle through both products and prices at the same time in the templates form.

Usually in python I would just make a simple while loop as such:

```
n = 0
while n < len(products):
   print products[n], prices[n]
   n+=1
```

I haven't found anything similar in the templates form yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if they are lists, I believe that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom template filter to get the nth item in the list, but this is what I would do:

Zip the 2 lists together in the view:

```
products_prices = zip(products, prices)
```

Then loop through that looped list in the template:

```
{% for product, prices in products_prices %}
    {{ product }}, {{ price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use forloop.counter, docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: Unless I am horribly misremembering things, there's no way to use the `forloop.counter` value to look up an element in another variable. You can use `prices.2` if you like, but not `prices.forloop.counter`.

Comment: Yes your right, I miss read the question. My bad Sorry about it.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

The built in template tags don't have an easy way to do this that I can recall. The simplest approach will be to zip the two lists together in your view, then provide the zipped data structure in the context. You could also write a custom `zip` template tag, if you're feeling adventurous.